# Can I build a string from an array with a value in between without iterating through the array twice?

Tags: javascript

I have two variables `name` and `values`, of which name is a simple string `Bob` and values is an array of strings.

Depending on the length of `values`, I would like to build a string, which consists of each value and an opening curly brace. But each opening curly brace needs a respective closing curly brace.

Assuming I have the following values: `["a", "b", "c"]`, my string should look like:

`a: { b: { c: { Bob } } }`

So what could be done inside template literal:

```
${values.map(v => ` ${v}: { `).join("")} ${name} ${values.map(() => `}`).join("")}
```

Is there another way than over `values` twice for the closing braces? My head is stuck.

Comment: You can convert the array into an object, then stringify it then remove the quotation marks.

Comment: Seeing your rep, I doubt this is an XY problem, so I can't help but wonder what your use case could be ? Also, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build an object, not another string? That said, [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) should work just fine.

Comment: @Seblor this is actually the problem description. I'm wondering whether, in order to archive this, I need to iterate over values twice. Or whether there is a way to elegantly get this string with one iteration but Bob in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const result = values.reduceRight((string, prop) => `${prop}: {${string}}`, 'bob')
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is pretty cool!

Answer (score 2):

This should do it (although I am not quite sure what you want to do with it, see @Seblor's comment):

```js
const nam="Bob", arr=["a","b","c"];

const res=[...arr,nam].join(": { ")+" }".repeat(arr.length)

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Yeah, neat! That's what I was talking about !

Comment: though to match the specified result, `res.slice(1, res.length-1)` (and probably with some template string syntax instead of using `+` for strings)

Comment: Agreed, there is some improvements. Wondering whether that one liner can be amended so to match without the slice

Comment: That would be ```const res = `${values.map(v => `${v}: {`).join(` `)} ${name} ${`}`.repeat(values.length)}`;```

Comment: Gave the acceptance to below, as I found that one to be even more neat.

Comment: Indeed, I fully agree! But please also check my latest update.

Answer (score 1):

This may not suit your specific task, but you could build up such an object by running reduce from the inside out:

```js
const path = ["a", "b", "c"];
const name = "bob";

const result = path.reduceRight((acc, v) => ({[v]: acc }), { name });

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Less fancy, but strictly avoids scanning the string twice.

```js
function addKey(keyArray, value) {
  if (keyArray.length === 0) return value;
  const key = keyArray.pop();
  return addKey(keyArray, { [key]: value });
}

const result = addKey(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'hello');
console.log(result);
```

The trick is to work backwards so you don't have to reverse the array.

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually yield the result specified in the post though, this yields JSON.